# Reinstall OS on GT-S5830i

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, installation, samsung-galaxy-ace

Is it possible to re-install the OS (Android 2.3.6) on to my GT-S5830i?

If yes, how can I get that done?

Comment: You need to get yourself a fitting ROM (aka [device-firmware](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/device-firmware/info), see also [rom tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info), [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)), and then flash it to your device (instructions are usually provided where the ROM is provided).

Comment: Why do you want to reinstall the OS? Have you replaced it with a custom ROM?

Comment: @DanHulme, perhaps the OP had an OTA update to ICS or something, and they wish to revert to an older version? Otherwise, it does seem strange to be asking how to revert (they already figured out how to install a custom ROM).

Comment: @StephenSchrauger I can make guesses too, but I think it's worth checking whether the OP genuinely needs to reinstall the OS. People from a Windows background sometimes think they should do that when they really just need to factory-reset.

Comment: For no particular reason, my phone becomes unresponsive. This has happened couple of times in the last 4-5 days and the only way I could bring it back to life is by removing and putting back the battery (nothing else works). I did try upgrading the firmware to the latest version but that has not worked. Is a factory reset an alternative? What all data will be erased if I do so? Thanks for the tips

Comment: A factory-reset is supposed to help here, yes. And you also assumed correctly that it would delete all your data (except that on SDCard), so you would need a good backup before -- for the stuff you want to keep, that is.

Comment: Ok, and 'data' would mean the contacts saved in the phone as well right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.you can reinstall the OS.

There's a low level flash tool called [heimdall](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/) (or [Odin](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1738841)) that can be used to reinstall the firmware or install [aftermarket firmware](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Cooper_Info) onto the Galaxy Ace.

Comment: Ah, http://sammobile.com has original firnware images...

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in Kies, by updating to factory version from the update menu